# Activar un TextBox cuando se seleccione un elemento del ComboBox

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Tengo un combobox con tres estados: Pendiente, Aceptado y rechazado. Lo que quiero es que cuando se elige Aceptado se me habilite un botón automáticamente en el formulario.
Estoy trabajando en C# (aplicaciones de Windows Forms).

Comment: Esto no suena muy difícil. ¿Qué has intentado?

Comment: una condición  el problema es que no supe como utilizarla ya que no se como es el evento cuando uno da click

Comment: Fuera de gran ayuda si pegas el código que tienes hasta ahora.

Comment: Los controles tienen una propiedad Enabled que los activa y desactiva, con eso solucionas lo del boton. Para el combobox revisa el evento selectionchanged y la propiedad value.

Answer (score 0):

Esta sería la manera más simple de conseguir que se habilite un botón al seleccionar un `Item` determinado desde un `Combobox`, recuerda primero dejar tu botón `Enable = false;`

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Aceptado")
     {
         button1.Enabled = true;
     }
}
```

Comment: Como observación, colocale un `else button1.Enabled = false; ` ya que si ha seleccionado `Aceptado` lo Habilitará  y si cambia el valor, se quedará habilitado. O simplemente hacer todo en una línea: `button1.Enabled = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Aceptado" ? true : false;`